# tvOS UITableView in UINavigationController causes strange fading behavior (UIView.mask)

Tags: swift, uitableview, mask, tvos

I ran into a strange situation when a UITableView is used within the context of a UINavigationController.

tvOS uses UIView.mask to apply a "fade-out gradient" at the top and bottom of a UITableView, so that cells fade into and out of existence at the top and bottom edges of the table view.

That's fine: the fading mask always stays out of the way of the selected cell.

(Here, view.backgroundColor is set to red and tableView.backgroundColor is set to blue with 50% alpha.  The constraints of the tableView are set to the safe area.)

[image]

The problem comes when you put your view controller inside of a UINavigationController.  When selection is near the top, the mask view no longer seems to avoid the cell, so it looks faded.  Additionally, as the user scrolls down, the fading mask takes a giant jump downward, and then as the user starts to scroll back up, that fading mask doesn't seem to get out of the way:

[image]

For reference, here is the same setup but with tableView.mask = nil:

[image]

(All fading is disabled, but you can see the cells "pop" into and out of existence at the top and bottom of the tableview.  You might think you could just set tableView.masksToBounds = true, but then the selected cell gets chopped off because it grows when selected)

Surely I'm missing something obvious here?  Did no one at apple put a tableview inside of a nav controller?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Do you have found something ?

Answer (score 1):

You were so close! The clips to bounds was missing.

```
tableView.clipsToBounds = true
tableView.mask = nil
```

Cheers :)